# Using read.table for specific columns of .csv files

Tags: r, import

I have tried asking this question before, but was a bit sloppy and confusing in delivering my data. For context, see [Importing fread vs read.table and errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566897/importing-fread-vs-read-table-and-errors/48585662?noredirect=1#comment84170557_48585662).

I want to read in a selection of columns from a bunch of .csv files and bind these together. As these .csv files are very big, it is not possible to import the files completely.

I tried to do this using the following piece of code for columns 1,2,3,25 and 29:

```
my.files <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
my.data <- lapply(my.files,fread, header = FALSE, sep=",", select = c(1,2,3,25,29)) 
df <- do.call("rbind", my.data)
```

However, using `fread` made the resulting datafile consist of characters, making it impossible to create good graphs. I tried to convert `character` data to `numeric` (see the context link), but that didn't work out as well.

When using `read.table` instead of `fread` on one of the files, the data is read in correctly. Therefore I would want to create a piece of code that does the same as the piece of code with `fread`, but with `read.table`. I tried the following code, but that didn't work.

```
my.files <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
my.data <- lapply(my.files,read.table, header = FALSE, sep=",", colClasses = c(1,2,3,25,29)) 
df <- do.call("rbind", my.data)
```

How can I read in specific columns from the .csv files with read.table and binding these together, while avoiding having to read in the complete files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First determine the number of columns `nc` in the files by looking at the first row of the first file.  Using `nc` set up the `colClasses` vector which should contain all `"NULL"` values except for the desired columns which should be `NA`.  Then read the files in using the `colClasses` vector we computed and `rbind` the resulting data frames together.

```
nc <- ncol(read.csv(my.files[1], header = FALSE, nrows = 1))
colClasses <- replace(rep("NULL", nc), c(1:3, 25, 29), NA)
my.data <- lapply(my.files, read.csv, header = FALSE, colClasses = colClasses)
do.call("rbind", my.data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Took a while, but in the end it worked.

Answer (score 0):

colClasses uses a vector defining the expected classes. 
Use "NULL" when you want to skip a column.

For example:

```
colClasses = c("character", NULL , "character")
```

In this case, columns 1 and 3 are set to character and column 2 is skipped.

Comment: NULL should be a quoted string, i.e. `colClasses = c("character", "NULL" , "character")`